# how to do sorting array by using typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a array ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7']
if user input 11237548, must =>1234578
which is i have to order by number
and check there are no double values

how can i finish this (logic) ?

Comment: Hi. Its not really a question about angularjs or typescript. You can look at how to sort array in javascript.You probably want to convert the strings to numbers also for the comparison. If you want to do the sort and distinct in one pass you can build the iteration loop yourself
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, you will have more success getting answers you need by providing your own code and asking questions about specific issues you run into. Try to solve the issue first and if you don't understand a specific aspect of why your solution doesn't work, ask that question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows no research or effort to solve the problem.

Comment: i try to push user input into array before .sort. however the input result is '1' ,'12','123' but not '1','2','3' =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you have two questions: 1) how to avoid duplicates; 2) how to sort the array after input.

**How to avoid duplicates**:

Method 1: check the array for the value before adding it.

```
const values = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']

// Simulate some input with duplicate values.
const input = '11237548'

// Split the input string into a character array.
const chars = input.split('') // ['1', '1', '2', '3', ...]

// Iterate over the characters.
chars.forEach((char) => {
  // indexOf returns -1 if the value isn't in the array already.
  if (values.indexOf(char) < 0) {
    values.push(char)
  }
})

// Result: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']
// This happens to be sorted because only 8 was added
// to an already sorted array.
```

Method 2: Use the `Set` class.

```
// Create a set with some starting values.
// A set does not add duplicates.
const values = new Set(['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7'])

// Simulate some input with duplicate values.
const input = '11237548'

// Use Array.from to split the input characters.
const chars = Array.from(input)

// Iterate over the characters.
chars.forEach((char) => {
  // The set will not add duplicates.
  values.add(char)
})

// Get an array of values from the set.
const list = Array.from(values) // ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']
```

**How to sort the array**

If the array will only contain numbers, convert the strings to numbers before adding
to the array.

```
let values = [1, 2, 6, 7]

const input = '3'

// Convert the input to a number.
const num = Number(input)

if (values.indexOf(num) < 0) {
  values.push(num)
}

// Values is currently unsorted: [1, 2, 6, 7, 3]

// Sort the array in place. The function will return a negative
// value when a < b, and a positive one when a > b.
values.sort(function (a, b) { return a - b }) // [1, 2, 3, 6, 7]
```

If you need the array to contain strings, convert to a number when sorting:

```
let values = ['1', '2', '6', '7']

const input = '3'

if (values.indexOf(input) < 0) {
  values.push(input)
}

// Values is currently unsorted: ['1', '2', '6', '7', '3']

// Sort the array in place. The function will return a negative
// value when a < b, and a positive one when a > b.
values.sort(function (a, b) { return Number(a) - Number(b) })
// Result: ['1', '2', '3', '6', '7']
```

Note: the above will not work as expected if the array contains strings which can't be converted to numbers.

Comment: thank you <3 it really help!

Comment: Glad I could help, @IVEjai!